# Difference between получится and удаётся

Tags: выбор-слова

My question is about two ways of saying "manage to do":

> у меня получится

and

> мне удаётся

Can anyone clarify what's the difference between these two? Thank you!

Comment: Note that you use different verb tenses here. "у меня получится" is Simple Future, while "мне удаётся" is Simple Present or Present Continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version *у меня получается* (*получится* in future tense) is typically about **ability** and **skills** (sometimes, about a *sсheduled opportunity*) while *мне удаётся* is more about **effort** and **luck** in getting a desired result.

> У меня получается превосходная уха.
>
> Я раньше не делала этот салат, но у меня явно получается.
>
> Пытаюсь сделать стойку на голове, но у меня не получается.
>
> У меня не получится приехать на Рождество из-за контрактных
>   обязательств.
>
> Мне не удалось с первого раза поступить в университет.
>
> Иногда мне удаётся поймать крупного лосося (или выбить 50 очков при
>   стрельбе и т. п.).
>
> При всём его коварстве, ему не удалось нас перехитрить.

Comment: Nice observation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should bear in mind that verbs usually have more than one meaning. So both verbs are complete synonyms in only one meaning, that is to succeed in doing something, to have a positive result

> Салат удался или салат получился на славу.
>   А вот обмануть меня ему не удалось или у него не получилось.

But besides these meanings there are others.which you can find in any dictionary.